# CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET and CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT

Tags: macos, rosmake, macos-mountain-lion, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi possible lifesavers,

I am just getting started with ROS, and now having trouble with rosmake.
When I try to do rosmake, it will give:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:190 (message):
    CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.6' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:
  
     " "
  
    is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
    CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
    empty.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
    
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Then I configured CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
Now, I am getting:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:190 (message):
    CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.6' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:
  
     "10.7"
  
    is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
    CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
    empty.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
    
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

which does not really make sense to me now.

So, any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50561/cmake_osx_deployment_target-and-cmake_osx_sysroot/) by [gegao884](https://answers.ros.org/users/3797/gegao884/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-15

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-01**:
I have the same issue too ... trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok this is what I did, go to `/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake` and comment out line 164 (with the `#` symbol) that say:

```
if(APPLE)
   #SET(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.8" CACHE STRING "Deployment target for OSX" FORCE)
endif(APPLE)
```

That seems to work for me so far. Maybe @WilliamWoodall might have a better idea.

I have OSX 10.8, ROS Groovy Beta 3, cmake 2.8.10.1, and XCode 4.5.2

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-01**:
Note, I tried changing the 10.6 to a 10.8 since I am using OSX 10.8 and it didn't help. Your line 164 of public.cmake will say 10.6.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-02**:
I didn't add this line, I'll have to look at the history to see when/why it was introduced.  I haven't run into this problem yet.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-21**:
That should be correct if you did not install it (for some reason) to `/opt/ros/groovy`. Make sure you do a make clean, that may help.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-21**:
Just look for the one which is under the path returned by `rospack find rosbuild`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in CMake.

This workaround should not be needed in the future:

http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/OSX-deployment-target-confusion-for-2-8-10-td7582284.html

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1